# MariaDB datetime automatic update bug

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

I don't know how can I explain that however when I try to update any datetime field in my table, MariaDB does update all other datetime fields.

I don't have any trigger, FK and any other automated system on my tables.

How can it possible? is it a bug? or something else?

I'm using Navicat but I tried to update code-side UPDATE query and didn't change anything.

any idea?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and let's see the query that is failing to update the datetime.

Comment: I found something in my code `create_time datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  update_time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I think, Navicat adds 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' code to all datetime fields.